# asp.net mvc 4 localization resource path too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I've created a class library in which I store my resource files for my asp.net mvc4 localization. I've been following the same folder structure as my Views.

I'm ending up having to reference strings such as:

```
@Resource.QuoteArea.Quote.Auto.DriverInfo
```

That is very long and tedious to type. Plus it makes my Views hard to read. Is there a better (neater) way for doing localization in mvc 4 ? Perhaps using a third-party library ? I already use mvccontrib for my model localization, so that's sorted. However for non-model related things, I'm facing the aforementioned issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the resource namespace in the resource properties, to make it shorter.  This blog post was very helpful for me, and will be for you to.

http://adamyan.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html